# Failed to define class org.h2.server.web.WebServlet

Tags: java, jsf, wildfly, h2

In order to using **H2 Console** in my (*JSF-2.3 / WildFly 26*) project, I added this *Servlet* to project *web.xml* file:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>H2Console</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.h2.server.web.WebServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>H2Console</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/console/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The project *pom.xml* file dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.212</version>
</dependency>
```

H2 `<data-source>` in *web.xml*

```
<data-source>
    <name>java:global/DataSourceName</name>
    <class-name>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</class-name>
    <url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=LEGACY</url>
</data-source>
```

I've got this error:

> Failed to define class org.h2.server.web.WebServlet in Module
> "com.h2database.h2" version 1.4.197 from local module loader @3d3ba765
> (finder: local module finder @25bc0606 (roots:
> F:\wildfly-26.1.0.Final\modules,F:\wildfly-26.1.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base)):
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link
> org/h2/server/web/WebServlet (Module "com.h2database.h2" version
> 1.4.197 from local module loader @3d3ba765 (finder: local module finder @25bc0606 (roots:
> F:\wildfly-26.1.0.Final\modules,F:\wildfly-26.1.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base))): javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet

Does anybody know how can I fix this compile time error?

Comment: `org.h2.server.web.JakartaWebServlet` should be used for Jakarta-based web servers (`org.h2.server.web.WebServlet` is for old `javax.servlet`-based servers) and you need to figure out why H2 1.4.197 is loaded instead of 2.1.212. But it looks like WildFly intentionally doesn't support usage of H2 Console servlet (https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFLY-14814) for a some reason.

Comment: *H2 1.4.197* is loaded because I used `MODE=LEGACY`. And I'm using *Java EE 8* not *Jakarta EE* @EvgenijRyazanov

Comment: H2 1.4.197 doesn't have that compatibility mode, it was introduced in H2 2.0.204 and it cannot load other versions of H2, it only allows usage of some invalid SQL commands.